# Fullscreen image with jquery on window resize?

Tags: jquery, fullscreen, each, window-resize

I am trying to make fullscreen images with jquery when the window resize function is triggered. But I get this kind of result - where you can see a gap at the bottom of the image which I don't know how to fix it.

[image]

the basic html,

```
<!-- container -->
    <div id="container" class="container">

        <div class="holder-supersize" id="supersize">

            <ul class="background-supersize">
                <li><a href="#"><img src="styles/images/IMG_0250.jpg" alt="" width="1000" height="667" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="styles/images/IMG_0255.jpg" alt="" width="667" height="1000" /></a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="#"><img src="styles/images/IMG_0323.jpg" alt="" width="1158" height="772" /></a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- container -->
```

jquery for updating image size on window resize,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).resize(function(){

        $(".holder-supersize").each(function() {

            //Define image ratio & minimum dimensions
            var minwidth = .5*(640);
            var minheight = .5*(480);
            var ratio = 480/640;

            //Gather browser and current image size
            var imagewidth = $(this).width();
            var imageheight = $(this).height();
            var browserwidth = $(window).width();
            var browserheight = $(window).height();

            //Check for minimum dimensions
            if ((browserheight < minheight) && (browserwidth < minwidth)){
                $(this).height(minheight);
                $(this).width(minwidth);
            }
            else
            {   
                //When browser is taller    
                if (browserheight > browserwidth){
                    imageheight = browserheight;
                    $(this).height(browserheight);
                    imagewidth = browserheight/ratio;
                    $(this).width(imagewidth);

                    if (browserwidth > imagewidth){
                        imagewidth = browserwidth;
                        $(this).width(browserwidth);
                        imageheight = browserwidth * ratio;
                        $(this).height(imageheight);
                    }

                }

                //When browser is wider
                if (browserwidth >= browserheight){
                    imagewidth = browserwidth;
                    $(this).width(browserwidth);
                    imageheight = browserwidth * ratio;
                    $(this).height(imageheight);

                    if (browserheight > imageheight){
                        imageheight = browserheight;
                        $(this).height(browserheight);
                        imagewidth = browserheight/ratio;
                        $(this).width(imagewidth);
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        });

    });

});
```

CSS for supersize image

```
/* Supersize -------------------------------------------*/

.holder-supersize {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    z-index:0;
}

.background-supersize {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}

.background-supersize li {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    text-align:center;
}

.background-supersize li img {
    /* for image with height < width */
    /**/
    width:100%;
    height:auto;


    /* for image with height > width */
    /*
    width:auto;
    height:100%;
    */
}

.background-supersize li ,
.background-supersize a,    
.background-supersize img{
    display:none;
    }

.background-supersize .active, 
.background-supersize .active a,
.background-supersize .active img{
    display:inline;
}
```

This is the link at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y8EDC/) and this is the link to see the [actual product](http://lauthiamkok.net/bin/supersize/index.php).

Any ideas what I have done wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code prevents skewing the image by locking the height to width ratio. Thus unless the window has the same ratio, you're either going to have space at the bottom (for a tall/narrow window) or space on the right (for a short/wide window).

If you want the image to get skewed, you can simplify the code a lot by simply making the height equal the window height and the width equal the window width.

Comment: @lauthiamkok: then you have to live with the space, there's no other way... well, unless you would prefer cropping the image? So if it's tall/narrow, the bottom is the bottom of the image but the right of the image will be cut off.